# Compass-based orientation app for blind users

Tags: android, gps, accessibility, navigation

I am looking for a voice-operated compass for blind users. Such users could use it to navigate an apartment or cross a not (too) dangerous road (although the latter application may be limited in scope).

This would be how it works. The user finds a straight edge, which would be a wall parallel to the sidewalk where the blind person is walking, or a wall's corner.

When the user find such a useful surface (which may really be anywhere, so long as the user knows about it and it's parallelness or perpendicularness in relation to where they want to walk), the user aligns the edge of their smartphone with the wall (or other) surface.

Then the user uses the S Voice command "open sound compass"  to open the sound compass app I am about to describe.

The app users the integrated compass to figure out the phone orientation. The user can say:

"Read bearing"

This reads the bearing. But as the user rotates, a sound wave is emitted continuously, with each sound representing a different bearing direction.

The user can say:

"Enable sound wave"

"Disable sound wave"

The user can also say

"Enable clicks"

"Disable clicks"

to have the phone produce clicks every 5 degree increments in angle. Each click will have a different sound quality and be produce one to match the user's direction in holding the phone in a specific direction.

...

So far so good, but now, suppose the user wants to walk straight. The user can say:

"Lock bearing"

The device, while the user walks, will produce an increasingly negative increasingly loud sound as the user deviates from the locked bearing, towards the left, and an increasingly positive increasingly loud sound as the user deviates from the locked bearing to the right.

When the user is done, crossing the road (after listening for cars to become silent (in a neighborhood, which would cause cars to drive more slowly)), they can simply issue the command:

"Unlock bearing".

Comment: No exact match, but coming close: [Magnetic Sense for the Blind](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antfu.magnetoreception) // [Vibe Compass](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=clark_and_company.vibecompass); also possibly of interest: [The vOICe for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vOICe.vOICe).

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I will sure check these out. Thanks.

Comment: Anytime! If one (or  more) of them is/are acceptable, consider answering your own question. I might even start a corresponding category in [my app lists](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php) then :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I will contact the developer for magnetic sense, see if they can help with implementing this key app, which should not be so hard to implement. That would be great. Thanks again. :-)

Comment: Once your answer is there, and I'm back from vacation, I'll see what I can do. Be welcome to ping me after Oct 5 in chat then :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy. Have a good vacation. :-)

Comment: Hi, Izzy. How are you doing? How was your vacation? Some time has passed, and I am still looking for this compass app for blind users. Any chance of having it implemented? Thanks.